# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Адресат вызова создал исключение." Не могу решить

Tags: c#, исключения, arduino

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace arduino
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            this.notifyIcon1.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon1_MouseClick);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);

            // Открываем порт, и задаем скорость в 9600 бод
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
        }

        private string path_vlag = "График_влажности.txt";
        private string path_temp = "График_температуры.txt";

        //****** поток ком порта
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string vlag = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            string temp = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), vlag, temp);
        }

        //запись влажности + запись температуры
        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string vlag, string temp);
        private void LineReceived(string vlag, string temp)
        {
            textBox1.Text = vlag;
            textBox2.Text = temp;

            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            // Создание файла и запись в него
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path_vlag))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(vlag);
                sw.WriteLine(date);
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path_temp))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(temp);
                sw.WriteLine(date);
            }

            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(date, temp);
            chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(date, vlag);
            chart1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0,30);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;

                //chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 30);
                //chart1.ChartAreas[1].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[1].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {           
                    string Y = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    string X = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
                    chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(X, Y);
                }
                chart1.Series[1].Points.Clear();
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string Y = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    string X = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Blue;
                    chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 1;
                    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(X, Y);

                }
                streamReader.Close();
            } 
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 30);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
            chart1.Series[1].Points.Clear();
            chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Blue;
            chart1.Series[1].BorderWidth = 1;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы не правили код дизайнера, то проблема, скорее всего, не в нем. Опубликуйте первичное исключение (разверните `innerException`) и пользовательский код `Form1` в формате [MVCE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Артём Оконечников добавил

Comment: Скорее всего, в `Form1_Load` вы обращаетесь к ChartAreas или Series по индексу, превышающему диапазон значений этих коллекций. Поставьте брекпоинт в методе и проверьте сколько элементов содержат эти значения

Comment: @Артём Оконечников простите, а где исправляется индекс, просто я новичок в этом...

Comment: `chart1.ChartAreas[0]` где `0` это индекс элемента массива.

Comment: @Артём Оконечников попробовал сменить, ничего не выходит

Comment: Максим, давайте пойдем от обратного. Попробуйте вначале закомментировать весь код в методе `Form1_Load`. Заработало? Если да, то раскомментируйте его по частям, вначале блок кода с `ChartAreas` затем с Series[0] и т.д. Локализуйте проблему. Когда поймете где конкретно ошибка, поставьте брекпоинт (F9 в VS) на строке, которая вызывает исключение и наведите курсором на свойство, посмотрите значение поля `Count` и учтите, что индекс коллекций начинается с нуля

Comment: @Артём Оконечников при закомментировании всего метода вылезла та же ошибка

Comment: значит закомментируйте всё в конструкторе после InitializeComponent

Comment: @Артём Оконечников не помогает

Comment: @Артём Оконечников я закомментировал все что связано с влажностью, то есть все что с Series[1] и все заработало